# bad file descriptor in c program with forks

Tags: c, fork, dup2

this program is supposed to simulate a posix shell in regards to commands with pipes. The example I've tried to simulate and wanna make work is "ls | nl", but it doesn't and I can't figure out why. I've debugged this code for many hours with no success.

I get the error: "nl: input error: Bad file descriptor", and when I've tried not closing any of the file descriptors or closing only some (or in only one of the forks, or only the parent, etc...), and the errors change, or it works but then nl keeps waiting for input. Anyways, I'm pretty sure the errors are in `fork_cmd` or `fork_cmds` and has to do with `close`.

I've included all the code. I know there's nothing wrong with parser.h. I know this is pretty shitty code but it should still work I think.

I'm probably blind, but I would really appreciate it if someone could help me figure it out. Hopefully it's something that I and maybe others can learn something from.

```
#include "parser.h"

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define READ  0
#define WRITE 1


void fork_error() {
    perror("fork() failed)");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void close_error() {
    perror("Couldn't close file descriptor");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


void fork_cmd(char* argv[], int n, int read_pipe[2], int write_pipe[2], int (*all_fds)[2]) {
    pid_t pid;

    switch (pid = fork()) {
    case -1:
        fork_error();
    case 0:
        if (read_pipe != NULL) {
            if (dup2(read_pipe[READ], STDIN_FILENO) < 0) {
                perror("Failed to redirect STDIN to pipe");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        if (write_pipe != NULL) {
            if (dup2(write_pipe[WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO) < 0) {
                perror("Failed to redirect STDOUT to pipe");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            if (close(all_fds[i][READ]) == -1 || close(all_fds[i][WRITE] == -1)) {
                close_error();
            }
        }

        execvp(argv[0], argv);
        perror("execvp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    default:
        printf("Pid of %s: %d\n", argv[0], pid);
        break;
    }
}

void fork_cmds(char* argvs[MAX_COMMANDS][MAX_ARGV], int n, int (*fds)[2]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (n == 1) {
            fork_cmd(argvs[i], n, NULL, NULL, fds);
        }
        // n > 1
        else if (i == 0) {
            fork_cmd(argvs[i], n, NULL, fds[i], fds);
        }
        else if (i == n - 1) {
            fork_cmd(argvs[i], n, fds[i - 1], NULL, fds);
        }
        else {
            fork_cmd(argvs[i], n, fds[i - 1], fds[i], fds);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if (close(fds[i][READ]) == -1 || close(fds[i][WRITE] == -1)) {
            close_error();
        }
    }
}

void get_line(char* buffer, size_t size) {
    getline(&buffer, &size, stdin);
    buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';
}

void wait_for_all_cmds(int n) {
    // Not implemented yet!

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int status;
        int pid;
        if ((pid = wait(&status)) == -1) {
            printf("Wait error");
        } else {
            printf("PARENT <%ld>: Child with PID = %ld and exit status = %d terminated.\n",
                   (long) getpid(), (long) pid, WEXITSTATUS(status));
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    char* argvs[MAX_COMMANDS][MAX_ARGV];
    size_t size = 128;
    char line[size];

    printf(" >> ");

    get_line(line, size);

    n = parse(line, argvs);

    // Debug printouts.
    printf("%d commands parsed.\n", n);
    print_argvs(argvs);

    int (*fds)[2] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2 * (n - 1)); // should be pointer to arrays of size 2

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if (pipe(fds[i]) == -1) {
            perror("Creating pipe error"); // Creating pipe error: ...
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("pipe %d: read: %d, write: %d\n", i, fds[i][READ], fds[i][WRITE]);
    }

    fork_cmds(argvs, n, fds);
    wait_for_all_cmds(n);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Your `get_line` function is dangerous. If the line is longer than 127 characters, then `getline` will try to reallocate memory for the passed buffer, and it will fail because `buffer` is **not** pointing to an address allocated by `malloc`/`realloc`. Your function yields undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yes, but this is not going to be used by anybody so it's fine. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: Why are you creating the pipes all in advanced and not one before the `fork` happens? I think the error might be there, but I have to test first.

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, post a [mcve] which this is not because the home grown header file: `parse.h` is being included, but the contents of that file is not posted.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  it is missing the `#define` statements for `MAX_COMMANDS` and `MAX_ARGV`

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <sys/wait.h>`  for the `wait()` function

Comment: the posted code is missing a body declaration for the function: `print_argvs()`

Comment: regarding: `int (*fds)[2]`  this is declaring an array of 2 pointers to `int`  Not what the code is actually wanting.

Comment: strongly suggest replacing: `get_line(line, size);` with a call to `getline()`, as exposed by the `stdio.h` header file.

Comment: strongly suggest always end the `case`s of a `switch()` statement via `break;`  even if the execution will never reach the `break;` statement.

Comment: in function: `main()`, this statement: `char* argvs[MAX_COMMANDS][MAX_ARGV];` declares a huge number of pointers to char.  Not what the code actually wants.  Suggest: `char* argvs[MAX_COMMANDS];` followed by `for( size_t i = 0; i<MAX_COMMANDS; i++) { argvs[i] = malloc( MAX_ARGV );  // check for success of malloc then }

Comment: the posted code fails to check the status of the call to `getline()`.  If `getline()` fails, then the program needs to pass the input buffer to `free()`.  When the function fails, it will return a -1.

Comment: in function: `fork_cmd()`, why is the code closing ALL the pipe file descriptors?

Comment: can the function: `parse()` return an error condition?  the code is not checking for such an error indication, and the call to `malloc()` is expecting its parameter to be `size_t` so suggest the `parse()` function return a `size_t`

Comment: what is expected to happen if the call to `parse()` returns 0 or 1?  then the call to `malloc()` will fail.  The code needs to allow for such 'corner' cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that one of the parenthesis was at the wrong place in both `fork_cmd` and `fork_cmds`, it should be like this of course: `close(fds[i][WRITE])`. This was the original code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    if (close(fds[i][READ]) == -1 || close(fds[i][WRITE] == -1))<--
    {
            close_error();
    }
}
```